# Attemp to call a nil value (field 'image')

Tags: lua

(node:9616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ^1SCRIPT ERROR: @photobooth/server/sv_main.lua:80: attempt to call a nil value (field 'image')^7
^3> ref^7 (^5@photobooth/server/sv_main.lua^7:80)
(node:9616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)

```
MySQL.Async.fetchAll(sqlQuery, {
    ['@id'] = data.Personalnumber
}, function(response)
    if response[1] then
        local sex
        if response[1].sex == "male" then
            sex = "Man"
        else
            sex = "Kvinna"
        end
        Player.addInventoryItem({
            item = 'idcard',
            data = {
                image = data.Image,
                firstname = response[1].firstname,
                lastname = response[1].lastname,
                personalnumber = response[1].id,
                sex = sex,
                length = response[1].height
            }
        })
        local sqlQuery2 = [[
                UPDATE
                    characters
                SET
                    image = @image
                WHERE
                    id = @id
            ]]

            MySQL.Sync.execute(sqlQuery2, {
                ['@image'] = data.Image,
                ['@id'] = response[1].id,
            })
        Player.setImage(data.image)    ---- this is line 80
    end
end)
```

end)

Comment: I don't know what data is but since you mostly used Image uppercase in the rest of the code I assume you should do this in line 80 too.